SSAS Tabular Model - Get table name of column dynamically using DAX
I am creating a calculation group within an SSAS Tabular model related to currency conversion that has three calculation items.
Each table in the model has a Base_Currency_ID with a relationship back to a Base Currency table. I need to be able to pass the Table Name of the SELECTEDMEASURE() back to a variable, similar to below.  Is there a DAX function that identifies the table name used for a column?
 VAR baseID = CONCATENTATE(*dynamicTableNameOfSelectedMeasure*,[Base_Currency_Id])

 RETURN 

 CALCULATE(
     SELECTEDMEASURE() * [Month Average Rate],
    'Base Currency'[Base_Currency_Id] = baseID,
   'Converted Currency Code'[Converted Currency Code] = "USD" )

I have tested the calculation below using a hard coded value for the variable baseID, however, I need the table name to be dynamic based on the respective SELECTEDMEASURE().
 VAR baseID = SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Order Detail'[Base_Currency_Id])
 Return

 CALCULATE(
     SELECTEDMEASURE() * [Month Average Rate],
    'Base Currency'[Base_Currency_Id] = baseID,
    'Converted Currency Code'[Converted Currency Code] = "USD")


You need to create measures for each table you have like the one you did for Sales Order Detail and then create calculation items in the calculation group to reference these measures based on the context of the measure you select :
CalculationItem =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISSELECTEDMEASURE([Measure_SalesOrderDetail]), [Measure_SalesOrderDetail],
    ISSELECTEDMEASURE([Measure_SalesOrderHeader]), [Measure_SalesOrderHeader],
    ISSELECTEDMEASURE([Measure_SalesInvoice]), [Measure_SalesInvoice],
    SELECTEDMEASURE() -- here you put your default case
)

If you prefer not to create many measures, you can create a table that makes the mapping between the measures and the base currency columns.

I am not certain I am following your suggestion.  Each FACT table has multiple measures, and a Base_Currency_Id.  Using the SELECTEDMEASURE() function will allow whatever measure a user selects in the reporting to have the logic of the calculated item applied.
The issue is I need to pass the table name of the selected measure back to a variable to pick up the correct exchange rate.
Is there a function or other method of retrieving the table name of a selected measure?

is it possible to share a pbix file with one example at least ?

The calculation group is created directly in the SSAS tabular model.  I don't think a PBIX file would assist in this case as it is a live connection to the tabular model.

You can use import with a tabular model
